My DX12 ray tracer is crashing and i can't figure out why
I am trying to code a real-time ray tracer application using DirectX12. I should say that I am almost a complete beginner about graphics programming and have very little idea on what I'm doing (if you are thinking of saying I should start with DX11 and then learn DX12, I am aware of that but because of time constraints, I can't really do that).
I followed NVIDIA's DX12 ray tracing tutorial to get the application to where it currently is and done all the extras up to shadows and lighting (shadows doesn't work but their code still does exist in the codebase). I am currently working on adding simple lighting.
My issue is that my application just crashes the moment I run it and I'm not entirely sure why. I tried asking ChatGPT and it told me I should check issues with descriptor heaps, SBT, root signature misalignments and shader without giving me any specifics. I have also tried to read the Microsoft documentation on SRV, CBV and UAV since those are used in the code that I believe is causing the crash but didn't understand much to be honest.
The geometry in the scene is just a tetrahedron with a plane underneath.
The code for creating the hit signature:
ComPtr<ID3D12RootSignature> D3D12HelloTriangle::CreateHitSignature()
{
    nv_helpers_dx12::RootSignatureGenerator rsg;
    //These are for the tetrahedron geometry that is in the scene
    rsg.AddRootParameter(D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_SRV, 0 /*t0*/); // vertices and colors
    rsg.AddRootParameter(D3D12_ROOT_PARAMETER_TYPE_SRV, 1 /*t1*/); // indices

    //These should be for the lighting from what I understand
    rsg.AddHeapRangesParameter(
        {
            { 2 /*t2*/, 1, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 1 /*2nd slot of the heap*/ },
            { 0 /*b0*/, 1, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV/*Scene Data*/, 2},
            //# DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
            { 3 /*t3*/, 1, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV/*Per Instance Data*/, 3},
        }
    );
    return rsg.Generate(m_device.Get(), true);
}

The code for creating the shader resource heap:
void D3D12HelloTriangle::CreateShaderResourceHeap()
{
    //4 entries needed: 1 UAV for the raytracing output, 1 SRV for TLAS, 1 CBV for camera matrices (#DXR Extra: Perspective Camera) and 1 SRV for the per-instance data (#DXR Extra - Simple Lighting)
    m_srvUavHeap = nv_helpers_dx12::CreateDescriptorHeap(m_device.Get(), 4, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV, true);

    //Get a handle to te heap memory on the CPU side so that descriptors can be directly written to
    D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE srvHandle_cpu = m_srvUavHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

    //UAV is the first entry based on what we defined in the root signature.
    //Create*View() methods write the view information directly into srvHandle.
    D3D12_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc = {};
    uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_UAV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    m_device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(m_outputResource.Get(), nullptr, &uavDesc, srvHandle_cpu);

    //Add the TLAS SRV right after the raytracing output buffer
    srvHandle_cpu.ptr += m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
    D3D12_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_RAYTRACING_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE;
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.RaytracingAccelerationStructure.Location = m_topLevelASBuffers.pResult->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    //Write the AS view in heap
    m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(nullptr, &srvDesc, srvHandle_cpu);

    // #DXR Extra: Perspective Camera
    // Add the constant buffer for the camera after the TLAS
    srvHandle_cpu.ptr += m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
    // Describe and create a constant buffer view for the camera
    D3D12_CONSTANT_BUFFER_VIEW_DESC cbvDesc = {};
    cbvDesc.BufferLocation = m_cameraBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    cbvDesc.SizeInBytes = m_cameraBufferSize;
    m_device->CreateConstantBufferView(&cbvDesc, srvHandle_cpu);

    // #DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
    srvHandle_cpu.ptr += m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
    srvDesc.Shader4ComponentMapping = D3D12_DEFAULT_SHADER_4_COMPONENT_MAPPING;
    srvDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
    srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D12_SRV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    srvDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
    srvDesc.Buffer.NumElements = (UINT)m_instances.size();
    srvDesc.Buffer.StructureByteStride = sizeof(InstanceProperties);
    srvDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D12_BUFFER_SRV_FLAG_NONE;
    m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_instancePropertiesBuffer.Get(), &srvDesc, srvHandle_cpu);
}

The code for creating the SBT:
void D3D12HelloTriangle::CreateShaderBindingTable()
{
    //The resources are bound (passed) to the shaders in this function.

    // The SBT helper class collects calls to Add*Program. If called several times, the helper must be emptied before re-adding shaders.
    m_sbtHelper.Reset();
    // The pointer to the beginning of the heap is the only parameter required by shaders without root parameters
    D3D12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE srvUavHeapHandle = m_srvUavHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();
    // The helper treats both root parameter pointers and heap pointers as void*, while DX12 uses the
    // D3D12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE to define heap pointers. The pointer in this struct is a UINT64,
    // which then has to be reinterpreted as a pointer.
    auto heapPointer = reinterpret_cast<UINT64*>(srvUavHeapHandle.ptr);

    // The ray generation only uses heap data
    m_sbtHelper.AddRayGenerationProgram(L"RayGen", { heapPointer });
    // The miss and hit shaders do not access any external resources: instead they
    // communicate their results through the ray payload
    m_sbtHelper.AddMissProgram(L"Miss", {});
    // #DXR Extra - Another ray type
    m_sbtHelper.AddMissProgram(L"ShadowMiss", {});

    // Hit shader setup
    m_sbtHelper.AddHitGroup(L"HitGroup", { (void*)m_tetrahedronVB->GetGPUVirtualAddress(),
                                           (void*)m_tetrahedronIB->GetGPUVirtualAddress(),
                                           (void*)heapPointer,
                                           (void*)m_perInstanceConstantBuffers[0]->GetGPUVirtualAddress(),
                                           (void*)m_perInstanceConstantBuffers[0]->GetGPUVirtualAddress(), });

    // #DXR Extra - Another ray type
    m_sbtHelper.AddHitGroup(L"ShadowHitGroup", {});

    // #DXR Extra: Per-Instance Data
    // The plane also uses a constant buffer for its vertex colors (for simplicity the plane uses the same buffer as the first instance triangle)
    m_sbtHelper.AddHitGroup(L"PlaneHitGroup", { (void*)m_planeBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress(),
                                                 nullptr,
                                                 (void*)m_globalConstantBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress(),
                                                 heapPointer });

    // Compute the size of the SBT given the number of shaders and their parameters
    uint32_t sbtSize = m_sbtHelper.ComputeSBTSize();

    // Create the SBT on the upload heap. This is required as the helper will use
    // mapping to write the SBT contents. After the SBT compilation it could be
    // copied to the default heap for performance.
    m_sbtStorage = nv_helpers_dx12::CreateBuffer(m_device.Get(), sbtSize, D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, nv_helpers_dx12::kUploadHeapProps);

    if (!m_sbtStorage)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Could not allocate the shader binding table.");
    }
    // Compile the SBT from the shader and parameters info
    m_sbtHelper.Generate(m_sbtStorage.Get(), m_rtStateObjectProperties.Get());
}

Common.hlsl
// Hit information, aka ray payload
// This sample only carries a shading color and hit distance.
// Note that the payload should be kept as small as possible,
// and that its size must be declared in the corresponding
// D3D12_RAYTRACING_SHADER_CONFIG pipeline subobjet.
struct HitInfo
{
    float4 colorAndDistance;
};

// Attributes output by the raytracing when hitting a surface,
// here the barycentric coordinates
struct Attributes
{
    float2 bary;
};


Hit.hlsl
#include "Common.hlsl"

// #DXR Extra - Another ray type
struct ShadowHitInfo
{
    bool isHit;
};

// #DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
struct InstanceProperties
{
    float4x4 objectToWorld;
    float4x4 objectToWorldNormal;
};

//This structure has the same bit mapping as the "Vertex" structure on the CPU side.
struct STriVertex
{
    float3 vertex;
    float4 color;
};

StructuredBuffer<STriVertex> BTriVertex : register(t0);
StructuredBuffer<int> indices : register(t1);
// #DXR Extra - Another ray type
// Raytracing TLAS, accessed as a SRV
RaytracingAccelerationStructure SceneBVH : register(t2);
//# DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
StructuredBuffer<InstanceProperties> instanceProps : register(t3);

cbuffer Colors : register(b0)
{
    float3 A;
    float3 B;
    float3 C;
}

//This is for the tetrahedron
[shader("closesthit")]
void ClosestHit(inout HitInfo payload, Attributes attrib) 
{
    float3 barycentrics = float3(1.0f - attrib.bary.x - attrib.bary.y,
                                 attrib.bary.x,
                                 attrib.bary.y);
    
    uint vertId = 3 * PrimitiveIndex();
    
    // #DXR Extra: Per-Instance Data
    float3 hitColor = BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 0]].color * barycentrics.x +
                      BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 1]].color * barycentrics.y +
                      BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 2]].color * barycentrics.z;
    
    //# DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
    //Normal computation
    float3 e1 = BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 1]].vertex - BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 0]].vertex;
    float3 e2 = BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 2]].vertex - BTriVertex[indices[vertId + 0]].vertex;
    float3 normal = normalize(cross(e2, e1));
    normal = mul(instanceProps[InstanceID()].objectToWorld, float4(normal, 0.0f)).xyz;
    //Position and direction computations related to lighting
    float3 worldOrigin = WorldRayOrigin() + RayTCurrent() * WorldRayDirection();
    float3 lightPos = float3(2, 2, -2);
    float3 centerLightDir = normalize(lightPos - worldOrigin);
    float nDotL = max(0.0f, dot(normal, centerLightDir));
    
    hitColor *= nDotL;
    payload.colorAndDistance = float4(hitColor, RayTCurrent());
}

//This is for the plane
// #DXR Extra: Per-Instance Data
[shader("closesthit")]
void PlaneClosestHit(inout HitInfo payload, Attributes attrib)
{
    // #DXR Extra - Another ray type
    float3 lightPos = float3(2, 2, -2);
    //Find the hit position in world space
    float3 worldOrigin = WorldRayOrigin() + RayTCurrent() * WorldRayDirection();
    //Calculate the direction towards the light from the position of the ray that hit the plane
    float3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos - worldOrigin);

    // #DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
    uint vertId = 3 * PrimitiveIndex();
    float3 e1 = BTriVertex[vertId + 1].vertex - BTriVertex[vertId + 0].vertex;
    float3 e2 = BTriVertex[vertId + 2].vertex - BTriVertex[vertId + 0].vertex;
    float3 normal = normalize(cross(e2, e1));
    normal = mul(instanceProps[InstanceID()].objectToWorldNormal, float4(normal, 0.f)).xyz;
    
    //The plane is double-sided, so we need to check whether we hit the front or back face of the plane.
    bool isBackFacing = dot(normal, WorldRayDirection()) > 0.0f;
    if (isBackFacing)
    {
        normal = -normal;
    }
    
    float3 centerLightDir = normalize(lightPos - worldOrigin);
    bool isShadowed = dot(normal, centerLightDir) < 0.0f;
    
    // Fire a shadow ray. The direction is hard-coded here, but can be fetched from a constant-buffer.
    RayDesc ray;
    ray.Origin = worldOrigin;
    ray.Direction = lightDir;
    ray.TMin = 0.01;
    ray.TMax = 100000;
    
    // Initialize the ray payload
    ShadowHitInfo shadowPayload;
    shadowPayload.isHit = false;
    TraceRay(
    // Acceleration structure
    SceneBVH,
    // Flags can be used to specify the behavior upon hitting a surface
    RAY_FLAG_NONE,
    // Instance inclusion mask, which can be used to mask out some geometry to
    // this ray by bitwise-anding the mask with a geometry mask. The 0xFF flag then
    // indicates no geometry will be masked
    0xFF,
    // Depending on the type of ray, a given object can have several hit
    // groups attached (ie. what to do when hitting to compute regular
    // shading, and what to do when hitting to compute shadows). Those hit
    // groups are specified sequentially in the shader binding table, so the value below
    // indicates which offset (on 4 bits) to apply to the hit groups for this
    // ray. The shadow hit group is the 2nd hit group in the SBT, so an index of 1.
    1,
    // The offsets in the SBT can be computed from the object ID, its instance
    // ID, but also simply by the order the objects have been pushed in the
    // acceleration structure. This allows the application to group shaders in
    // the SBT in the same order as they are added in the AS, in which case
    // the value below represents the stride (4 bits representing the number
    // of hit groups) between two consecutive objects.
    0,
    // Index of the miss shader to use in case several consecutive miss
    // shaders are present in the SBT. This allows to change the behavior of
    // the program when no geometry have been hit, for example one to return a
    // sky color for regular rendering, and another returning a full
    // visibility value for shadow rays. Shadow miss program is the 2nd miss program,
    //so an index of 1.
    1,
    // Ray information to trace
    ray,
    // Payload associated to the ray, which will be used to communicate
    // between the hit/miss shaders and the raygen
    shadowPayload
    );
    float shadowFactor = shadowPayload.isHit ? 0.3f : 1.0f;
    float3 hitColor = float3(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.3f) * shadowFactor;
    
    if (!isShadowed)
    {
        isShadowed = shadowPayload.isHit;
    }
    
    // #DXR Extra - Simple Lighting
    float factor = isShadowed ? 0.3 : 1.0;
    float nDotL = max(0.f, dot(normal, lightDir));
    hitColor = float3(0.7, 0.7, 0.7) * nDotL * factor;
    payload.colorAndDistance = float4(hitColor, 1);
}

Any help would be much appreciated. Also if you need any additional piece of code or information I will add those with an edit.

Without prying into why anyone with no D3D12 experience is attempting to use the DXR API, consider that DXR is quite difficult to get right even for seasoned D3D12 developers. Dumping all your code here with no further information than "it doesn't run" is also not helpful.

Any output from the debug layer?

@Carsten
D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandAllocator::Reset: A command allocator 0x000001EADAE08740:'Unnamed ID3D12CommandAllocator Object' is being reset before previous executions associated with the allocator have completed.
D3D12 ERROR: CGraphicsCommandList::SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable: The descriptor heap (0x000001EAE2B8AC60:'Unnamed ID3D12DescriptorHeap Object') containing handle 0x45678a00130000 is different from currently set descriptor heap 0x000001EAE2B8A950:'Unnamed ID3D12DescriptorHeap Object'.
After these I get a DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG error followed by the removal of the device.

There you have it. Both appear to be synchronization errors. You have to make sure you insert fences and wait for them at the right locations before re-using resources currently accessed during rendering. Make sure to always have the debug layers enabled during development and fix errors as soon as they arise. Also keep the Agility SDK updated (in case you use it - otherwise, start using it), as there are more cases covered by the debug layer in later versions.

@Carsten I'll take a look at that, thanks!
